# How to use NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault in Pyobjus

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, kivy

how i can use NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault to connect website in

```
import ios
url = 'https://exapmle.com'
web_view = IOSWebView().open(url)
```

i need to use NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault p12 file to auth in https://example.com in the webview